# Large delay in GCM push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I put in reference [this Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

I implemented it it works but am facing troubles:
first sometimes I need to restart the android emulator so the push notification could be delivered when the emulator is restarted the push notification work properly.
after a while the push notification does not work and it need about 15 min to the push notification to get delivered. if I restart the emulator the push notifications get delivered and so on...

what do you think the problem here?

Comment: the GCM service take about 10s and delivery is not guarantee. The emulator restarting has no relation with receiving push notification. Insure server retry mechanism in error case.

Comment: In my case, it was not router/firewall issue. When running on physical device, I got notification/cloud message without any delay, however, when running on an emulator, only the first notification arrives with ~30min delay; however, once I received the first one, from there one, no delay. I believe it has to do with how heartbeat is handled on an emulator. As suggested by Satyendra, I just turn off wife/data of the emulator and turn right back on and it works. As Yogesh suggested, its not a solution, but works.

Answer (score 2):

Its your wifi router probably, check the description here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andqlimax.pushfixer

I opened an issue to google here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/connecting-to-networks-and-devices/fslYqYrULto

and they agree there is a TCP timeout on some conditions.

Answer (score 2):

if you are expecting a notification but there a huge delay in android emulator.
You can perform following step to get instant notification.

**Turn off the mobile data in Emulator then turn it on again, you will get the notification as soon as you turn it on**
hope this helps :)

Comment: this is not solution

Comment: i know this is not the solution but it can help to get notifications and can be used as an alternative if one could not find any proper solution. :)